# Testing fixtures with addReference in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm working on a Symfony's project and i have some issues while testing with phpunit.

I have StatusFixtures with `addReference` to be used in BriefFixtures and this work correctly when i do `doctrine:fixtures:load` (with correct dependency to load Status before Brief). 
But, when i run my tests, using those fixtures, the following error is coming : `Error: Call to a member function addReference() on null`

My StatusFixtures.php

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Status;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class StatusFixtures extends Fixture
{
    const Status_Reference = 'status';

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // some code to assign values

        $manager->persist($activeStatus);
        $this->addReference(self::Status_Reference, $activeStatus);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

My BriefFixtures.php

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Brief;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;

class BriefFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // some code to assign values
        $briefValid->setStatus($this->getReference(StatusFixtures::Status_Reference));
        $manager->persist($briefValid);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return array(
            StatusFixtures::class,
        );
    }
}
```

And i'm loading fixtures this way in my tests

```
private $entityManager;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();

        $status = new StatusFixtures();
        $status->load($this->entityManager);

        $fixture = new BriefFixtures();
        $fixture->load($this->entityManager);
    }
```

And my error `Error: Call to a member function addReference() on null`

`$this` from StatusFixtures seems to be null, but i don't understand why this correctly works when i'm loading fixtures and no more when i'm running my tests.

Maybe something is missing in setUp() ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Use Alice bundle fixtures. This tool is awesome when it comes to haveing tests in fixtures

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the [Symfony documentation for Fixtures](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html). It makes you feel like 
`$fixture->load($this->entityManager);` will simply load the fixture, but that is not true. It is simple when you use the command `doctrine:fixtures:load` because it does more than just above load function call.

Going with third party solutions will be the quickest and probably the best solution. Here are few libraries that you can use:

1. [liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle)
2. [hautelook/AliceBundle](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) (thanks michal)

The error you are getting comes from `ReferenceRepository` object that is supposed to store the references, but it is null. Who actually sets up this repository, it is `Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\AbstractExecutor.` What you need is a Loader that loads the fixture by creating everything needed for it to work. One of those loaders is  `Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Loader\SymfonyFixturesLoader` that your command `doctrine:fixtures:load` is using. You can use that loader or write your own loader. [You can see](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/blob/master/Loader/SymfonyFixturesLoader.php) that what this loader has to do to provide you the expected results. But that still is not it, you also need `Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor` because your Fixture is a database entity and you need to persist it. [You can see that 
how](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/blob/17519bf4c11a4850689f2f7cd6e98d0c72738035/Command/LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php#L85) `doctrine:fixtures:load` makes use of SymfonyFixturesLoader and ORMExecutor to provide you expected result.  So, you will have to write your own solution for this. I worte a Loader for myself before because I didn't want to go with third party solutions. I am putting it below. It may not serve your purpose exactly, but it will give you ideas how to write your own Loader if you want to.

```php
namespace App\Tests\Extra;

use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Tests\Extra\Exception\FixtureNotLoadedException;

class FixtureLoader
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $loader;
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        ManagerRegistry $registry
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function loadFixtures(array $classNames) : void
    {
        $this->loader = new Loader();

        foreach ($classNames as $className) {
            $this->loader->addFixture(new $className());
        }

        $executor = new ORMExecutor($this->entityManager, new ORMPurger());
        $executor->execute($this->loader->getFixtures());
    }

    public function getFixture(string $className) : Fixture
    {
        if ($this->loader == null) {
            throw new FixtureNotLoadedException(
                sprintf(
                    'The fixture %s must be loaded before you can access it.',
                    $className
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->loader->getFixture($className);
    }

    private function getPurger() : ORMPurger
    {
        $purger = new ORMPurger($this->entityManager);
        $purger->setPurgeMode(ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_TRUNCATE);

        return $purger;
    }

    public function cleanDatabase() : void
    {
        $connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection();

        $mysql = ('ORM' === $this->registry->getName()
            && $connection->getDatabasePlatform() instanceof MySqlPlatform);
        if ($mysql) {
            $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
        }
        $this->getPurger()->purge();
        if ($mysql) {
            $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
        }
    }
}
```